# Angular table and HTML Checked Boxes with Disabling Feature in Remaining Checked Boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, node.js

The goal is to have all the checked boxes become disabled when one box is checked. When I use this jquery code below, for some reason it does not work as it does in the SO solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43269816/html-form-programmatically-disable-remaining-checked-boxes-in-html-form/43270164#43270164).

In this example I am populating a table using a MVC controller in a nodejs and angular stack. When this table displays, there is a checkbox next to each name that prints in the table. **Is there a solution to correctly disable the checkboxes being populated in this angular script when one checked box is selected?**

html

```
<table>
<thead>
   <th>Names</th>
</thead>
<tr dir-paginate="x in names | filter:search | itemsPerPage:8">
   <div class="checkbox" id="nameList">
      <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="name" value={{x.name}}>  {{ x.name }}</label></td>
   </div>
</tr>
</table>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#nameList input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $('#nameList').find(':checkbox').not($(this)).attr('disabled',true);
    }else{
        $('#nameList').find(':checkbox').attr('disabled',false);
    }
    });
})
```

Comment: Why you are using jquery to handle all this, if you are using angular??

Comment: this will be hard since you use a loop to create the checkboxes. You can use the `ng-change` or `ng-click` combined with `ng-disabled` but the problem is it will disable all of your checkboxes including the selected one.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ng-change and ng-model directives of angular to handle all these things.

Refer here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D.

Comment: since he is using a loop to populate the table with checkboxes, it would be hard to track individual checkboxes through ng-model

Comment: @JKAlombro can you provide an example how to use ng-change directives to disable checked boxes?

Comment: @JMM oh sorry I'm 2 days late. Sure I can but I'll post it to answers instead since it's a little bit long.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it using angular's `ng-change` with `ng-disabled`. `ng-change` executes an angular function whenever some changes was made to an input field(in this case, checking and unchecking the checkbox), `ng-disabled` on the other hand disables the input fields if the condition is `true`

On your template, put these to your checkbox input tag

```
<tr dir-paginate="x in names | filter:search | itemsPerPage:8">
   <div class="checkbox" id="nameList">
       <td>
          <label>
           <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="isCBdisabled" ng-model="yourCBmodel" ng-change="cbChanged()" name="name" value={{x.name}}>
              {{ x.name }}
          </label>
        </td>
   </div>
</tr>
```

Then on your angular controller, put this

```
$scope.isCBdisabled = false;

$scope.cbChanged = function() {
    $scope.isCBdisabled = true;
};
```

So this is what I did, on my controller, I initialized a `scope` `isCBdisabled` into false so that it wont disable the checkboxes right away. Then made a function `cbChanged()` that changes `isCBdisabled` into true causing the checkboxes to be disabled because of `ng-disabled`. However, just like i`ve said, it will disable all checkboxes including the selected one so that's another thing to brainstorm.